# Como agrupar itens em uma lista com uma devida condição?

Tags: c#, lógica

Possuo uma lista com uma propriedade chamada `tamanho` que pode conter dois valores: "M" ou "I".

Eu preciso que essa lista seja aleatória, porém com uma condição de agrupamento.

"M" seria de meia página e "I" de inteira. Ou seja, eu preciso ter sempre 1 inteira e depois 2 meias. Nunca 1 inteira, 1 meia e depois 1 inteira de novo.

Vou usar isso para gerar um PDF, logo conforme for varrendo a lista ele vai inserir 2 meias na mesma página, ou 1 inteira, e nunca 1 meia e mais uma inteira em seguida, pois a inteira não caberá na mesma página da meia e vai ficar um espaço.

**A minha dúvida é sobre a lógica que preciso aplicar na lista para obter esse resultado. Não faço ideia ainda e preciso de ajuda.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código é apenas uma lista C#.

```
List<Questao> questao = new List<Questao>();
// questao.Questao.TipoTamanhoQuestao acessa o valor "M" ou "I"
```

Comment: Teria como apresentar o código implementado até o momento?

Comment: O código é apenas uma lista C#. Não vi necessidade de colocar.

Comment: Uma pequena observação: a variável devia chamar-se `questoes` e não `questao`, já que é uma lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa esta extensão. Ela percorre a lista e:

- se encontrar uma questão de tamanho "I", retorna-a imediatamente
- se encontrar uma questão de tamanho "M", guarda-a num buffer até encontrar um par correspondente. Quando o par for encontrado, ambas serão retornadas.

Se houver alguma questão "M" sem par, irá ser retornada no final.

```
public static class QuestoesExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<Questao> Grouped(this IEnumerable<Questao> questoes)
    {
        Questao buffer = null;

        foreach(var q in questoes)
        {
            if(q.TipoTamanhoQuestao == "M")
            {
                if(buffer == null)
                {
                    //Se a questao for de meia pagina, guardar num buffer ate que outra questao M apareça
                    buffer = q;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Quando um par de questoes M forem encontradas, retornar ambas
                    yield return buffer;
                    yield return q;
                    buffer = null;
                }
            }
            else yield return q;
        }

        //Se for encontrada alguma questao M sem par, retorná-la no final
        if(buffer != null)
            yield return buffer;
    }
}
```

Utilização:

```
var grouped = questoes.Grouped();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nol3mp